# Slice and attribute in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, slice

I am tried to create a slice in django template and get an attribute.
How can i do in django template something like this:

python code:

```
somelist[1].name
```

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are accessing a single element of a list, you don't need the `slice` filter, just use the dot notation.

```
{{ somelist.1.name }}
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#variables) for more info.

Comment: How did i forgot about that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in tag [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) with a combination of [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% with somelist|slice:"1" as item %}
    {{ item.name }}
{% endwith %}
```